# How to download file to my server (Yii framework) from another server?

Tags: php, curl, yii

I need my webapp to create a file on the server from another server. Input parameter is URL of a remote file. I stumbled upon cURL wrapper for Yii. Is it right tool for my task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. No need of third-party modules. Here is a draft version:

```
<?php
$f1 = fopen($_REQUEST['pic_url'],'r');
$fcontent = $contents = stream_get_contents($f1);
fclose($f1);

$fileName = microtime().'.'.CFileHelper::getExtension($_REQUEST['pic_url']);

$f2 = fopen(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../images/'.$fileName,'c+');
fwrite($f2,$fcontent,strlen($fcontent));
fclose($f2);
?>
```

Basically this code reads an image on remote server and saves it on home server.